# how to access aws rds in eks in same vpc and subnet

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I am working on importing data from rds using debezium cdc source connector from eks. rds and eks share same vpc and subnet.
And i added the eks security group to rds security group, but it was not connecting.
As a test, we added the IP of the pad to the RDS security group, but we confirmed that it works well.
Is there anything else that should be touched by eks iam or security group? eks security groups are both inbound and outbound open!

Comment: Are you getting any error message when the connection fails?

Comment: @chamal i solved it! I added a security group incorrectly. thanks for reply!